# How to remove the category from the page url?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to remove the "**Project**" term from the below permalink/url?
[www.fourmanteam.com/project/camping](http://www.fourmanteam.com/project/camping)

I want the url in below order.
[www.fourmanteam.com/camping](http://www.fourmanteam.com/camping)

I tried the custom structure. But, no help.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: I mean, I tried with a Custom Structure in Permalink Structure. Not a code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, "**Project**" is your custom taxonomy.

So while registering your taxonomy you need to pass following rewrite rule:

```
$args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => '/' ),
        );
register_taxonomy( 'Project', array( [custom_post_type_slug] ), $args, array( 'rewrite' => array ('slug'=>'/')));
```

After applying this code, you need to flush rewrite rules. For that you just need to save permalink setting again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin (or other similar). It won't change the permalink itself, but at least it will allow you to have a shorter link to the category page.